# Can't save data and reloadTableView from closure

Tags: swift, swift5

I'm newbie in Swift. I have a connection to websocket (use Starscream) and I am waiting to receive text or an event in this method:

```
func websocketDidReceiveMessage(socket: WebSocketClient, text: String)
```

When I get an event (just ID) I trigger `func fetchInfoAboutInvitations(text: String)` from another viewcontroller; this func refers to http request (get from server all information about event), this func with `completion:`

```
func gettingInfoAboutInvitationAfterSocket(invitationId: String, completion: @escaping (Invitations) -> Void)
```

Then I go back to fetchInfoAboutInvitations function, in order to try to:

```
info.getInfoAboutInvitationAfterSocket(invitationId: text)
{ (invitation) in
     print("some inv: \(invitation)") // -- here i got data
     self.arrList.append(invitation)
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
  self.tableViewController.reloadData()
}
```

On this:

```
var arrList = [Invitations]() {
    didSet {
        print("arrList: \(arrList)")
    }
}
```

I have a printout with my data, but tableview is empty. If I rerun my app, my tableview will be not empty. Another function works fine:

```
func getCurrentEvent() {
    currentInvitations.getCurrentInvitations { (value) in
        print("currentInv value get CURINVI: \(value)")
        self.arrList.append(value)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableViewController.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

My viewDidLoad:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableViewController.delegate = self
    tableViewController.dataSource = self
    getCurrentEvent()
}
```

I guess the reason that I can't append data in var arrList = Invitations is because I have no func fetchInfoAboutInvitations(text: String) in viewDidLoad, but I can't add it in, because it is a closure

Update:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arrList.count
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = tableViewController.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? EventControllerCell {
        cell.nameLabel.text = arrList[indexPath.row].id
        return cell
    }
    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

Update #2, add some detail:
Here i get event from websocket(server)

```
func websocketDidReceiveMessage(socket: WebSocketClient, text: String) {
      print("websocketDidReceiveMessage text: \(text)")
        do {
            let welcome = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Welcome.self, from: text.data(using: .utf8)!)
            print("welcome: \(String(describing: welcome))")
            print("welcome dataDataId: \(String(describing: welcome?.data.data.objectID))")
            print("welcome eventType: \(String(describing: welcome?.data.eventType))")

            if let invitationId = welcome?.data.data.objectID {

                let event = EventController()
                event.fetchInfoAboutInvitations(text: invitationId)

            }
        }
```

Then i trigger:

```
func fetchInfoAboutInvitations(text: String) {
    let info = InfoAboutInvitation()
    info.getInfoAboutInvitationAfterSocket(invitationId: text) { (invitation) in
        print("some inv: \(invitation)")
        self.arrList.append(invitation)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableViewController.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Its request with completion:

```
func getInfoAboutInvitationAfterSocket (invitationId: String, completion: @escaping (Invitations) -> Void) {

    guard var urlComp = URLComponents(string: "") else {return}
    urlComp.path = ""
    guard let url = urlComp.url else { return }

    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.setValue("a")
    request.addValue("", forHTTPHeaderField: "")

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("URLSession error")
            print(error!)
        }

        guard let data = data else {
            print("data is empty")
            return
        }

        do {
            let getData = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Invite.self, from: data)

            let invitionData = Invitations(id: getData.id, initiator: getData.initiator, receiver: getData.receiver, group: getData.group, created: nil, status: getData.status, replieadAt: getData.replieadAt)
                print("info about invitationData (infAbout): \(invitionData)")
                completion(invitionData)
        } catch let err {
            print(err)
        }

    }
    task.resume()
}
```

If the problem is not clear, could someone tell me please how to realize this with another way? I don't know how I can it use with delegates\protocols (and how to implement this).

I ran the app on another PC, and now I have null in tableView, when closure works:

```
func fetchInfoAboutInvitations(text: String) {

    info.getInfoAboutInvitationAfterSocket(invitationId: text) { (invitation) in
        print("some inv: \(invitation)")
        self.arrList.append(invitation)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableViewController.reloadData() // - here I got nil
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your tableViewController is an instance of UITableViewController, you need to call `reloadData()` on the `tableView` attribute of your UITableViewController,  like `self.tableViewController.tableView.reloadData()`

Comment: No, its UITableView

Comment: Can you please share your `func tableView(UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection: Int) -> Int`, `func numberOfSections(in: UITableView) -> Int`, and `func numberOfSections(in: UITableView) -> Int` implementations?

Comment: I added "update" in main post
P.S. when i run app first time (when work method viewDidLoad) my tableView isnt empty (if i have some event). Problem is with update new event in tableView